# which is better - EventKit or LocalNotification for reminders to app users

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, eventkit

I am building an app that reminds users when it's time to do something. I was planning on using EventKit to add events to calendars, which could make for a very cluttered calendar as there could be multiple reminders during a day.

Is LocalNotification a more appropriate solution?

Is it easier to delete future LocalNotifications than EventKit calendar events if the user wants to delete future occurrences?

What are the pros and cons of each?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking over the same thing.  I think you want to go with local notifications because, besides less clutter in the calendar as you pointed out, you have more flexibility over creating a calendar event:
- you can choose a custom alert
- you can have the reminder launch back into your app as an option, and then customize how your app will behave when it's launched from a reminder (i.e. go to the specific item that the reminder was about)

Plus Apple says you're not supposed to be creating events directly in the user's calendar, but presenting a dialog to the user and let them click ok (the name of the view controller for this purpose is escaping me right now). This might be an extra step over what you had in mind for your app's workflow.

There was a limit on the number of localnotifications one app could have - 64 i believe- so you may want to check if that's changed in ios5.